# How to exclude/remove an input after the php code is executed.?

Tags: php, html, forms, include, require

So i have an post input where i submit data something simple.

```
<form method="post" action="result.php">
    <input type="url" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="http://example.com/">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

After the html code  is going to be executed a php code which echo success or something like this that doesn't matter.

But i have a problem when i include('submit.php') it's going to show also the input and i don't want this.

How i can do that to don't show the input on result.php?

Comment: what do you mean input? Please be clear and specific as possible

Comment: You can use `ob_get_contents()` and `ob_set_contents()` to control your data flow from PHP.

Comment: PS: NEVER call anything submit in a form if you ever want to submit it programmatically

Comment: Add your PHP code

Comment: I don't think my php code matter that much beacuse it's a simple echo and that's it. What i want it's the input box to not be shown anymore on result.php

Comment: So... this isn't a "php" question then. The tag needs to be removed. It's misleading to those such as I that follow that tag. Same thing goes for the "include" and "require" tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be user-specific, you can try to use cookies or sessions like this:

`index.php`

```php
<?php
session_start();
?>

<?php if(!isset($_SESSION['show_button']) && !$_SESSION['show_button'] ){ ?>
<!-- Button logic here... -->
<?php } ?>
```

`result.php`

```php
// If the url has been entered, it returns a false from empty()
$_SESSION['show_button'] = empty($_POST['url']);
```

Comment: I just want to the following string to doesn't be shown on result.php ```<form method="post" action="result.php">
    <input type="url" name="url" class="form-control" placeholder="http://example.com/">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>```